# Destructuring an object with "delete" as property

Tags: javascript, object, properties, destructuring

In Javascript, is it possible to destructure an object with "delete" as one of its properties?

```javascript
class MyClass {

    constructor ( { prop1, prop2, delete, prop4 } ) {

        this.prop1  = prop1
        this.prop2  = prop2
        this.delete = delete
        this.prop4  = prop4

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete` is a reserved keyword, you cannot have that as a *variable name*. Therefore you have to rename it during destructuring:

```
  { delete: otherName }
```